# xml maxLength for decimal type

Tags: xml, xsd

I tried the following to set the maximum length for a decimal:

```
<simpleType name='xxx'>
    <restriction base='decimal'>
        <maxLength value='7'/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

but this is not valid syntax. Can I use maxLength for decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `minInclusive` and `maxInclusive` instead.

An example from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp):

```
<xs:element name="age">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

There are also `minExclusive`, `maxExclusive` and `totalDigits` restrictions.

Comment: minExclusive and maxExclusive is for value restriction. For decimal field totalDigits can be used.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i use maxLength for decimal?

A correct answer would require checking the W3C Recommendation, but a check of my quick reference: `maxLength` only applies to string types.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use totalDigits instead:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xdarch.html